# Ignore some files when using viminfo+=%

Tags: buffers, startup, viminfo

I use in my vimrc the following option:

```
set viminfo+=%
```

This allows vim to open the last edited files if you don't pass any arguments to vim.

Is there a way to ignore some files? I want to disable the opening of files like COMMIT_EDITMSG, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`:help viminfo-%`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#viminfo-%25) gives you some hints on how to achieve this:

> Quickfix ('buftype'), unlisted ('buflisted'), unnamed and buffers on removable media (|viminfo-r|) are not saved.

I would simply make those files *unlisted*; as Vim is invoked from the version control system for the commit message, and usually no other files are edited within that session, the buffer listing (`:ls`) and naviation (`:bnext`) isn't particularly important there, anyway.

For `COMMIT_EDITMSG`, you can hook into the existing filetype detection:

```
autocmd FileType gitcommit setlocal nobuflisted
```

or set up your own pattern(s):

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead COMMIT_EDITMSG setlocal nobuflisted
```

Comment: Thanks, it's just what I wanted.
If I need to ignore differents files, I need to add one line per file? Isn't it?

Comment: You can specify several filenames as a comma-separated (but without blanks!) list; cp. `:help autocmd-patterns`.